# Torrent tracker sites blacklist

Tags: networking, bittorrent, blacklist

I'm trying to add a blacklist of torrent sites IPs for my local(10 people at home) network. I don't have problems with adding it, but with getting it. I thought that googling would be enough, or maybe I entered a bad phrase but I find it really hard to find some except paid ones.

Is that somehow **private** or **pricey** thing? I mean, it doesn't need to be a super large list, only some main sites that people know. I know that blacklisting(even with a very good blacklist) is not a solution, but it may turn off somebody.

Please, can somebody provide a link or a small blacklist for non-commercial use at home? Or share your opinion on this "not so technical" topic why are they so private.

Comment: What do you have in your network to administer this ? are you trying to do this just over home router ?

Comment: just over home router via adress lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say making your router to use **OpenDns** & then choosing to block **P2P/FileSharing** would be easiest & most effective.

### This is how you should go about it

1. Create an account with [OpenDns](https://www.opendns.com/)
2. Setup rules

   [image]
3. Set your router to use **OpenDns**

   [image]

*This should be enough to deter an average home user but you know its never enough when it comes to computers :)*

Comment: Tried it, It's working fine, but I made a blacklist to my needs manually, thank you :)